# Difference between $this->input->post() and $_POST[]?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

What is the difference between `$this->input->post()` and `$_POST[]` in codeigniter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$_POST` is a native [PHP superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)

`$this->input->post()` is a method of the CodeIgniter [Input Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html)

From their documentation:

> The Input Class serves two purposes:
>
> 1. It pre-processes global input data for security.
> 2. It provides some helper methods for fetching input data and pre-processing it.

So, `$this->input->post()` is a helper method provided by CodeIgniter. Instead of having to check if a value is set in `$_POST`, retrieve it and then protect the value from security issues such as XSS attacks, you simply use `$this->input->post()` and let it do the work for you.

This the whole point to using a framework. It takes care of details like this for you, so you can focus on implementing business logic.

Answer (score 0):

`$this->input->post()`  is using for getting one single value from view in controller, and in another hand, `$_POST[]` is using for getting entire values from view in controller. We can also use `$_POST['some_value']` at the place of `$this->input->post()`

Answer (score 0):

Working of both the function is same it will fetch the `HTTP POST variables`.

`$_POST` is a native PHP superglobal variable (which means that they are always accessible, regardless of scope - and you can access them from any function, class or file without having to do anything special.)

```
 e.g. $_POST['form name goes here']
```

`$this->input->post()` is a CodeIgniter's built in function. It will contain the 2 parameter. first parameter will contain the name of the POST variable. 2nd parameter optional. second optional parameter lets you run the data through the XSS filter. It's enabled by setting the second parameter to boolean TRUE.

```
e.g. 
$this->input->post(NULL, TRUE); // returns all POST items with XSS filter

$this->input->post(); // returns all POST items without XSS filter
```